# Redis for Storing session for Rails. why my key is hashed value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redis

I use redis for storing rails session.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store,
  url: ENV['REDIS_URL'],
  key: '_my_site_session',
  expire_after: 1.day
```

I can see that in client browser (Cookies), session cookies is stored with key. some thing like that.

```
_my_site_session:"0f1483b12090bbad4f351643fc4cfc26"
```

but I can't find key-value pair in my Redis.

```
❯ redis-cli key 0f1483b12090bbad4f351643fc4cfc26
(error) ERR unknown command `key`, with args beginning with: `0f1483b12090bbad4f351643fc4cfc26`,
```

***Instead of that,
I see some new key-value pair has been created.***

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "stat:failed"
2) "MacBook-Pro.local:29950:baab15a038c2"
3) "stat:failed:2022-06-08"
4) "processes"
5) "stat:processed"
6) "2::9557f0fd1a32df2ec57b553e79b1bde40fadf878cb6e0ed24f19f6f47376749c"
7) "stat:processed:2022-06-08"

127.0.0.1:6379> get "2::9557f0fd1a32df2ec57b553e79b1bde40fadf878cb6e0ed24f19f6f47376749c"
"\x04\b{\bI\"\x11redirect_url\x06:\x06EFI\".http://localhost:3000/borrowers/dashboard\x06;\x00TI\"\x13user_return_to\x06;\x00TI\"\x19/borrowers/dashboard\x06;\x00TI\"\x10_csrf_token\x06;\x00FI\"1I5Oasz4v9kNJhggcW7TaOV3Ud/1M/4xDLrU44DOH9Lg=\x06;\x00F"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

looks like the sessions stored. Why redis key has been encripted? can I find my session using original-key(0f1483b12090bbad4f351643fc4cfc26)?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Eventually I got the answer. you can use `session.id.private_id` to get that encrypted id present in the Redis. For more details check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77346121/how-where-does-devise-warden-generate-the-cache-key-used-to-store-a-session-in-r