# How/Where does Devise/Warden generate the cache key used to store a session in Redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redis, devise, warden

In my Rails application using Devise and Redis, I can call these things and get a session's ID:

```
# app/controllers/some_controller.rb

session.id
session[:session_id]
cookies['session_cookie']
```

The value returned for all of the above matches, and - as an example - let's say it's `aaaabbbbccccdddd1111222233334444`.

While that is happening in the app, I can run the console and get the cache key for the session:

```
# in the Rails console

redis = Redis.new
redis.keys
```

What shows up there looks nothing like the ID from before. It's something more like `_session_id::2::984375urehgiuhfhe754w9873987e98trieydfijdoewsdjfh948570398408esf`.

The question(s) is(are):

1. How/When/Where does Devise (or is it Warden?) generate the cache key?
2. How is the cache key related to the Session ID?
3. Is there a way for a Rails controller to access or programmatically arrive at the session's corresponding cache key?

Comment: It's neither Devise nor Warden. It's Rails own session storage middleware. The Warden wiki [has a pretty good overview](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Overview). Then you're asking 3 different questions with a very broad scope. Generating the cache key is done by [ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CacheStore.html) and it's the same as the session indentifier stored in the cookie.

Comment: You can get the session id with `session.id` but you never really need to.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It helped me learn that even though `session.id` returns a string, the returned item is actually an `sid` object which responds to `public_id` (the string returned) and `private_id` (something similar to what I see when I call `Redis.new.keys`). The results is that I was able to call `CacheStore`'s `cache_key` method with `session.id.private_id` and get exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks again! I'm going to post it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Max's comment above, I dove into ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore's code and understood that a session's id is actually not just a string, but an object passed around as `sid` inside that code. The object carries both a `public_id` (which is the string returned) and a `private_id` (which looks more related to what I see in Redis).

Based on my original example:

```
session.id
# 'aaaabbbbccccdddd1111222233334444'

session.id.public_id
# 'aaaabbbbccccdddd1111222233334444'

session.id.private_id
# '2::984375urehgiuhfhe754w9873987e98trieydfijdoewsdjfh948570398408esf'

# and in the console:
redis = Redis.new
redis.keys
# ['_session_id::2::984375urehgiuhfhe754w9873987e98trieydfijdoewsdjfh948570398408esf']
```

Seeing the `private_id` makes the Redis key far less mysterious.

To get there precisely, I called something like
`session.instance_variable_get('@by').send(:cache_key, session.id.private)`, where `@by` is some kind of CacheStore-related instance and `cache_key` is the private method that generates the key used to interface with Redis.